# Rails 5 ActiveRecord optional inclusive where for nested association's attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Assuming this simplified schema:

`users has_many discount_codes`

`discount_codes has_many orders`

I want to grab all `users`, and if they happen to have any `orders`, only include the orders that were created between two dates. **But if they don't have orders, or have orders only outside of those two dates, still return the users and do not exclude any users ever.**

What I'm doing now:

```rb
users = User.all.includes(discount_codes: :orders)

users = users.where("orders.created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?", date1, date2).
or(users.where(orders: { id: nil })
```

I believe my OR clause allows me to retain users who do not have any orders whatsoever, but what happens is if I have a user who only has orders outside of date1 and date2, then my query will *exclude* that user.

For what it's worth, I want to use this orders `where` clause here specifically so I can avoid n + 1 issues later in determining orders per user.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's keeping you from simply defining an `orders_in_timespan` method in your `User` model and doing `orders.where(created_at: date1..date2)` there?

Comment: @ClemensKofler nothing at all, but perhaps I'm missing something, but I can't see how that fixes the problem at hand. I need a way to make sure users are not excluded; simply adding a User-level scope such as that would exclude any users from the query whos orders do not meet the created_at condition

Comment: From my understanding, you want all users – and for users with orders in a given time frame, you also want these orders => fetch all users, iterate over them and for those who have orders in the time frame, use the orders as you see fit. Here's what I mean in code: https://gist.github.com/clemens/62c324f1b60adc5ce10094b56c1c58d9. You basically render all users and if they have orders that fit your criteria, you do something with them (in my example that "something" is simply rendering them).

Comment: I can see why this would work but it has a couple issues that make it untenable for my use case:

1. I'm trying to serialize data to json and
2. Ideally do it within 1 query.

Is what I'm trying to accomplish simply not possible with ActiveRecord in one query?

Comment: In reality, you're rendering 2 types of resources that have a one-to-many relationship. The way to do this with just one single query would be an `OUTER JOIN` but that then includes duplicate data (because each user is repeated for each order). This is also why Rails has generally shifted to having 2 queries in such cases (1 for users and then 1 for all relevant orders).

Comment: users = users.where("orders.created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?", date1, date2)  + users.group("orders.id").having('COUNT("orders.id") = 0')

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense to try and control the orders that are loaded as part of the where clause for users.  If you were to control that it'd have to be part of the includes (which I think means it'd have to be a part of the association).

Although technically it can combine them into a single query in some cases, activerecord is going to do this as two queries.
The first query will be executed when you go to iterate over the users and will use that where clause to limit the users found.
It will then run a second query behind the scenes based on that includes statement.  This will simply be a query to get all orders which are associated with the users that were found by the previous query.  As such the only way to control the orders that are found through the user's where clause is to omit users from the result set.

If I were you I would create an instance method in User model for what you are looking for but instead of using where use a select block:

```rb
def orders_in_timespan(start, end)
    orders.select{ |o| o.between?(start, end) }
end
```

Because of the way ActiveRecord will cache the found orders from the includes against the instance then if you start off with an includes in your users query then I believe this will not result in n queries.

Something like:
`render json: User.includes(:orders), methods: :orders_in_timespan`

Of course, the easiest way to confirm the number of queries is to look at the logs.  I believe this approach should have two queries regardless of the number of users being rendered (as likely does your code in the question).

Also, I'm not sure how familiar you are with sql but you can call .to_sql on the end of things such as your users variable in order to see the sql that would be generated which might help shed some light on the discrepancies between what you're getting and what you're looking for.

Comment: I agree that the where clause probably belongs on the join instead if I want to go that way. What would that look like, does AR provide a way to have a condition on the join? For your solution, I'm currently already doing something like that, the problem with moving it from a DB-level query to a ruby-based query is that it starts to consume quite a bit of memory with my data set. Is there a way to keep it all in AR or SQL?

Comment: Well you can provide conditions on an association so you could make an association on the user model for discounted orders.  Then as long as you're not doing something like a limit in that you could probably just includes that association when making your original query  `User.includes(:discounted_orders)`.  You also may get some benefit from the method find_each as you could use it to only load a fraction of the users at a time.  Of course technically that will result in more queries but if the set of users is large you may find a good memory tradeoff from it.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: Write a custom query in SQL (ugly).

Option 2: Create 2 separate queries like below...

```
@users = User.limit(10)
@orders = Order.joins(:discount_code)
  .where(created_at: [10.days.ago..1.day.ago], discount_codes: {user_id: users.select(:id)})
  .group_by{|order| order.discount_code.user_id}
```

Now you can use it like this ...

```
@users.each do |user|
  orders = @orders[user.id]
  puts user.name
  puts user.id
  puts orders.count
end
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use joins instead of includes. Rails `joins` use inner joins and will reject all the records which don't have associations.

```
User.joins(discount_codes: :orders).where(orders: {created_at: [10.days.ago..1.day.ago]}).distinct
```

This will give you all distinct users who placed orders in a given period of time.

Comment: We want to retain users who do not have any orders (i.e., never exclude any users)

Answer (score 0):

```rb
user  = User.joins(:discount_codes).joins(:orders).where("orders.created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?", date1, date2) + 
        User.left_joins(:discount_codes).left_joins(:orders).group("users.id").having("count(orders.id) = 0")
```